# Keep duplicate column names when subsetting in R

Tags: r, duplicates, subset

I have a dataframe with duplicate column names in R, when I select specific columns from this dataframe using subset it renames the duplicates making them distinct. When I am creating a dataframe using the function data.frame() I can stop this happening by using the argument check.names = FALSE, is there a way I can also do this using subset (or any other way which selects names columns).

For example say I have the dataframe

```
data <- data.frame('sample' = 50, 'x_mean' = 1.5, 'Lower CI' = 1.0, 'Upper CI' = 2.0, 'sample' = 50, 'y_mean' = 0.6, 'Lower CI' = 0.3, 'Upper CI' = 0.9, check.names = FALSE)

selectVec <- c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)
```

Using the code

```
subset(data, select = selectVec)
```

renames the duplicate confidence intervals 'Lower CI.1' and 'Upper CI.1', whereas I want to keep these as 'Lower CI' and 'Upper CI'. Does anyone know a way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you will get the same behavior with `[`. The only way I can think of is to reassign the names afterwards:

```
subdata <- data[, selectVec, drop = FALSE]
names(subdata) <- names(data)[selectVec]
```

However, be aware that having duplicated column names is a very unnatural, complicated (obviously) and risky format for keeping your data. I would try to understand why the file or data.frame had  duplicated columns in the first place and fix it there.

Comment: Thanks, yep I'd tried with [ as well with same results. Renaming the dataframe after is probably the best way.

Answer (score 2):

This method will avoid passing it through `[.data.frame` which would then require reassigning the names. Dataframes are lists and logical indexing works with them the same way it works to address columns of dataframes.

```
    data.frame(as.list(data)[ selectVec ], check.names=FALSE )
#  sample x_mean Lower CI Upper CI y_mean Lower CI Upper CI
#1     50    1.5        1        2    0.6      0.3      0.9
```