# Pivotlonger with identical Column names

Tags: r

my data looks like

```
Nr. Type 1 Type 2 Type 1 Type 2
1     400    600    100   800
2     500    400    900   300
3     200    200    400   700
4     300    600    800   300
```

and I want to create Boxolplots of Type 1 and type 2.
Pivotlonger makes Type 1 and Type 1.1 which is not what I Need.

Maybe someone can help me.

Comment: I can't replicate the problem.  I used `pivot_longer()` from `tidyr` (v 1.2.0) and that doesn't produce the result you describe.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out your issue was not with the `pivot_longer()` but with the subsetting of your original `data.frame` using `[`. There is no direct control over the requirement that the output of `[` or `base::subset()` have unique column names so you need do something else to subset your data and avoid losing column names. This is discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415312/keep-duplicate-column-names-when-subsetting-in-r) question so borrowing from one of the answers, you can use:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# data with extra column to be removed
d <- structure(list(Nr. = 1:4, `Type 1` = c(400L, 500L, 200L, 300L), x = 1:4, `Type 2` = c(600L, 
400L, 200L, 600L), `Type 1` = c(100L, 900L, 400L, 800L), `Type 2` = c(800L, 
300L, 700L, 300L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

# remove extra column without changing names then pivot
data.frame(as.list(d)[-3], check.names = FALSE) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Nr.) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(name, value)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, but in general my data looks like yours. After pivot longer I get    ```Nr    Profile  meters
   <chr> <chr>     <int>
 1 1     Type 1     21990
 2 1     Type 2     14196
 4 1     Type 1.1   23728
 5 1     Type 2.1   18349``` before my data looked like yours and I had to use names() to rename the columns.  And my code is ```Profile[,c(1,10,12,14,20)] %>%  
+   pivot_longer(-Nr., names_to = "Profile", values_to = "meters")```

Comment: My data looks like in my question, but has more columns between the selected. If I give a look to my whole data, there are the right column names. But when I use the 
`Profile[,c(1,10,12,14,20)]`, I get the names Type 1 and Type 1.1.

Comment: The issue isn't `pivot_longer()`, it's with subset `[`. See solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415312/keep-duplicate-column-names-when-subsetting-in-r